# How to export multiple gridviews into a single pdf file in dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 11 grid view in my page I want to export it into single pdf file, I searched this query and implemented the code which I got but it didn't work and generate pdf with black background only headers is showing not the content. Please provide me the code to export all 10 grid views into single pd

```
protected void btnExportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
    GridView[] gvpdf = new GridView[] { GV1,GV2,GV3,GV4,GV5,GV6,GV7,GV8,GV9,GV10,GV11}; 
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f); 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms); 
    pdfDoc.Open();
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < gvpdf.Length; i++)
            {
                if (gvpdf[i].Visible)
                {
    
                    PdfPTable pdfTbl = new PdfPTable(gvpdf[i].HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
                    pdfTbl.SpacingAfter = 20f;
    
                    foreach (TableCell headerTblCell in gvpdf[i].HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
                        font.Color = new BaseColor(gvpdf[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerTblCell.Text));
                        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvpdf[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                        pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                    }
    
    
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvpdf[i].Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (TableCell tblCell in gvRow.Cells)
                        {
                            System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
                            font.Color = new BaseColor(gvpdf[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                            PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblCell.Text));
                            pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvpdf[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                            pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                        }
                    }
                    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTbl);
                }
            }
    
            pdfDoc.Close();
    
    
            byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report_" + ".pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(content);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: I rather doubt you're going to get much luck here unless you update your question quite significantly. Stackoverflow is more "help me fix my code that doesn't work" than it is "please give me code that works" so if anyone provides an answer here, I'd be surprised.

Comment: That said, check out DevExpress. I personally hate 3rd party suites like DevExpress with a passion, but in this case it might be your best bet as it has built-in PDF exporting.

Comment: Now,Please Help Ortund.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try another approach. Just read all your data from mentioned grids, store it in POCO classes and then use some library to convert this information into a PDF file with desired formatting.

Personally, I recommend a free and open-source library called [QuestPDF](https://www.questpdf.com/) (notice, I am its creator). It offers an easy to use fluent API, [detailed documentation](https://www.questpdf.com/documentation/api-reference.html) and [a getting started tutorial](https://www.questpdf.com/documentation/getting-started.html) showing how to generate an invoice document.